# Python: Basic L-System: Axiom and Rules

Tags: python, function, dictionary

The tests (the calling of the function) that I am using are:

```
rewrite('A', {'A':'AB','B':'A'}, 2) >>> 'ABA'

rewrite('A', {'A':'AB','B':'A'}, 4) >>> 'ABAABABA'

rewrite('A', {'A':'AB','B':'A'}, 0) >>> 'A'
```

They are not working and I can't figure out what the problem is. This is an L-System that essentially stacks a rule upon another rule depending on how many iterations the user request, [here is an example](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/Strings/TurtlesandStringsandLSystems.html) of what I mean.
I know this can be done using multiple functions, but I have to figure out how to run it all in one.

```
def rewrite(word, prod, n):

    start1 = list(prod.keys())[0]
    rule1 = list(prod.values())[0]
    start2 = list(prod.keys())[1]
    rule2 = list(prod.values())[1]
    newWord = ""

    if word == start1:
        newWord = rule1
        newWord1 = ""
        i = 0
        for i in range(n):
            for x in newWord:
                if x == start1:
                    newWord1 = newWord1 + rule1
                    newWord = newWord1
                    i += 1
                elif x == start2:
                    newWord1 = newWord1 + rule2
                    newWord = newWord1
                    i += 1
                else:
                    newWord1 = newWorld1

    if word == start2:
        newWord = rule2
        newWord1 = ""
        i = 0
        for i in range(n):
            for x in newWord:
                if x == start1:
                    newWord1 = newWord1 + rule1
                    newWord = newWord1
                    i += 1
                elif x == start2:
                    newWord1 = newWord1 + rule2
                    newWord = newWord1
                    i += 1
                else:
                    newWord1 = newWord1  

    else:
        newWord1 = word    # no rules apply so keep the character

    return newWord1
```

I know that I can do it this way and that this way works:

```
def rewrite(word, production, n):
    for i in range(n):
        newWord = ''
        for x in word:
            if x in production:
                newWord += production[x]
            else:
                newWord += x
        word = newWord
    return word
```

But I spent a lot of time on the one above, and although it is very complicated, I wanted to know if I was on the right track.

Comment: What does it mean "They are not working"?

Comment: @BUZZY The top function is not outputting the correct answer.

Comment: What was wrong with the bottom one? Why make a more complicated one?

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 The bottom one works fine. I just spent a few hours on the top one before I realized the other way. I just wanted to know if anybody knows where I went wrong in the top one?

Comment: Wait, so you want to replace the bottom one with the top one? It's nice, simple, compact, accepts any number of rules. Why bother with the old and ugly code?

Comment: "But I spent a lot of time on the one above, and although it is very complicated, I wanted to know if I was on the right track." - unfortunately, you weren't. It's not just a matter of fixing "the problem"; your failed attempt is *deeply* wrong, with lots and lots of problems.

Comment: I'll go ahead and say that you were not on the right track. Abandon the old method. Don't throw good time after bad. I answered with one problem, but honestly, I can't even figure out what you're going for. You have something that works, move on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that this/these line(s) are your problem:

```
i += 1
```

You can't skip steps in a loop in python like that. Python `for` loops over a range don't work like in other languages. You can manipulate the value of of the loop variable all you want, but the next iteration will still be what it was going to be anyway.

So basically, you're not skipping over the temporary steps that you think you're skipping. So the rules are just being applied haphazardly.